# Release of method variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Please see this code:

```
 -(id)MethodName:arg {
    // some stuff
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // some more stuff
    [dateFormatter release];
}
```

dateFormatter is a method variable (i.e. not an instance variable; it's not defined in the header file). Yet, the method is creating a pointer and allocating memory. It turns out that the program crashes if I release the variable as in the last line, but works ok if not. I don't understand why if I create a pointer and allocate memory, then do not need to use release. Apart from this, should I set dateFormatter to nil after its use?

Comment: What's that stuff that's happening?

Comment: Your problem is probably somewhere in `// some more stuff`. Your code looks perfectly fine, otherwise.

Comment: For future reference, these variables are called "local variables" (not method variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's probably happening is that you're passing the `dateFormatter` to some other method that just `assigns` it to some instance variable. Then you release it, effectively deallocating it. Finally, the class that now has a reference to deallocated memory tries to use the instance variable and the program crashes.

What you should do is have the receiving class `retain` the variable when it receives it (and also `release` the instance variable that points to it in its `dealloc` method).

If you're assigning it to a property, you should define it with the `retain` modifier, e.g.:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter;
```

Comment: @Jordao: I believe the conflicting line is this: `NSString *myDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];`  Yet I don't see your point, as dateFormatter:stringFromDate returns a NSString (that is an object independent from DateFormatter. But I believe your point applies to the following line: `[self setSubtitle:myDate];`. Here, the instance variable Subtitle points to myDate, that is a method variable that dies when the method ends (my former code also contained a `[myDate release]`)

Comment: Ahh, `setSubtitle` should `retain` that `NSString`, because it assigns it to an instance variable.

Comment: Ohh, and don't release `myDate`, you're not the owner!

Comment: @Jordao: tks for sharing... and sorry for the noob question: subTitle is a property. I can't see the setSubtitle method. How do I retain the NSString? Should I override the method (write it?). Also, what do you mean I'm not the owner of myDate? I'm not the owner because I didn't use alloc and init? The stringFromDate (convenience) method is the owner, right? Is that method's responsibility to handle the release?

Comment: Define it like: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *subTitle`.

Comment: You should only release objects that you own. You only own objects that you allocate with `alloc`, create with `new`, or copy with `copy`, or if you `retain` it. You didn't use any of these methods to create `myDate`, therefore you shouldn't release it.

Comment: Look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) for the full story.

Comment: Currently it is defined as `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;` What's the difference between `copy` and `retain`? (sorry for another noob question). Also, should I care about releasing it afterwards? Looks like I will have to read again the memory management chapter...

Comment: `copy` is OK. And you must release it later in the `dealloc` method.